# Accessing heavily nested array when parsing JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to parse JSON using Javascript but having trouble accessing the value that is 568 part on the first PWER object (this value changes and I just want to display it on the page). The **'1452520496000'** part also changes value based on time. I'm new to javascript and JSON, the examples that I've seen in researching tend to be simpler than this, such as accessing the PWER in "cid" : "PWER" which I can do.

Here is a sample of the JSON output from the API:

```
[
{"cid":"PWER",
 "data":[{"1452520496000":568}],  
 "sid":"144",
 "units":"kWm",
 "age":5
 },

{"cid":"MOTN",
 "data":[{"1452520489000":0}],
 "sid":"910",
 "units":"S",
 "age":12
 },

{"cid":"LGHT",
 "data":[{"1452520489000":19.09}],
 "sid":"910",
 "units":"L",
 "age":12}
 ]
```

I have adapted code from the example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp) as a skeleton for the HTTP GET request while I work out how to parse this. This is what I have so far:

```
  <div id="main"></div>

  <script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "URLGoesHere";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  function myFunction(response) {
      var arr = JSON.parse(response);

      var out = arr[0].data[0];

      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = out;
  }
  </script>
```

The issue is that this just displays *[object Object]* on my page.

I've been trying to use the console to debug this:

```
console.log(arr[0]);
```

> Object {cid: "PWER", data: Array[1](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp), sid: "144", units: "kWm", age:
>   5}

This shows that it is managing to access the API using the token and pull data.

I want to access 'Array1' in 'data' so I check to see what that contains:

```
console.log(arr[0].data);
```

> [Object]
>       0: Object
>   length: 1
>   __ proto __: Array[0]

I next try to access the object which is 0 in the index:

```
console.log(arr[0].data[0]);
```

> Object {1452520496000: 568}

The 568 value that I want is there but I cannot access it, the 1452520496000 part is forever changing. How would be the best way of going about accessing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would have to use [`Object.keys(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the key you are after

```
var data = arr[0].data[0];
var keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log(keys[0], data[keys[0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = arr[0].data[0];

console.log(obj[ Object.keys( obj )[ 0 ] ] );
```

get all the keys inside `obj` using `Object.keys()` into an array and then get the first index (first key name) from it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON works on key value pair formula. The object you are using doesn't fit in JSON format.

```
"data":[{"1452520496000":568}],
```

You can use above data like below two formats:

1. Use both in array `"data":[ "1452520496000", "568"],`
2. Use some keys `"data":{"key1":"1452520496000", "key2" : "568"},`

and if you want to use the same format then I found a way to parse your JSON

```
var d= 'your json';
var parsedObjects = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(d));
```

Stringify json and then parse.

Answer (score 0):

epascarello has a good answer. An alternative would be to do a simple loop through the POJO in 'data'. A simple for loop example (though you could use other, more performant loops):

```
var data = arr[0].data[0];
var out;
for (var key in data) {
    out = data[key];
}
```

Note that if there are other keys present in that 'data' object, you will have to add some error checking before assigning 'out'. E.g. if you have this:

```
{
    ...
    data: [{ "foo": "someval", "1452520496000": 568, "bar": "someotherval" }]
```

... Then you would need to do some validation inside your loop to verify the current key is the correct one. I would also then break as soon as you find the right key, for perf.